# Форматирование строк C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

При работе со строками столкнулся с проблемой форматирования. Есть класс параметра, в котором содержится свойство `Value` строкового формата.
При изменении, свойство валидируется с помощью регулярного выражения на соответствие формату числа int или double (Посредством реализации интерфейса IDataErrorInfo).
Так же в классе параметра имеется метод, который отвечает за само форматирование строки под число. Его задачи:

1. Замена входящей точки на запятую
2. Устранение пробелов из строки
3. Обрезка лишних нулей в начале строки

XAML-разметка имеет привязку к `Value` и тут возникает пара интересных моментов:
При использовании `UpdateSourseTrigger` в значении `LostFocus` все работает, как и задумано, но если изменить его на `PropertyChanged`, то я сталкиваюсь со странным поведением:

1. Если в начале строки подставить один или несколько нулей, то логика форматирования не применяется. Применяется, только если изменить число в конце строки
2. Пробелы в строку подставляются, как ни в чем не бывало
3. Если поставить в начале строки точку, то валидация перестает работать вообще (Даже в случае с LostFocus)

[image: Некорректный формат]

Мне нужно использовать триггер на изменение свойства.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? И как вообще рекомендуется решать подобные задачи?

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Border BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Value: "/>
        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30" Width="100"
                 TextAlignment="Center"
                 ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"
                 Text="{Binding Parameter.Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}"/>
        <!--Кнопка просто для потери фокуса-->
        <Button Grid.Column="2" Width="70" Content="Focus off"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

MainViewModel.cs:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public Parameter Parameter { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Parameter = new Parameter(55);
    }
}
```

Parameter.cs:

```
public class Parameter : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private const string DoubleRegex = "^[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]+$";

    private string _value;

    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            _value = Format(value);
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        }
    }

    public string Error => null;

    public string this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            string error = null;

            if (propertyName == nameof(Value))
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(Value, DoubleRegex))
                {
                    error = "Введите число";
                }
            }

            return error;
        }
    }

    public Parameter(double number)
    {
        Value = number.ToString();
    }

    private string Format(string str)
    {
        var replaced = str.Replace('.', ',').Trim();

        var nullsNumber = 0;

        foreach (var letter in replaced)
        {
            if (letter.Equals('0'))
            {
                nullsNumber++;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        int cutTo;

        if (replaced[nullsNumber].Equals(','))
        {
            cutTo = nullsNumber - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cutTo = nullsNumber;
        }

        var result = replaced.Substring(cutTo);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: А почему вы формируете так самостоятельно результат? Если у вас есть допустим `int` (111222) и вам надо вывести его как `000 111 222`, то используйте стандартное [формирование строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/formatting-types), конкретно в моем примере, это было бы просто [`000 000 000`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yI0U71). То есть к чему это я, если у вас есть `int 100`, то он и должен быть таким в коде, а уже при выводе, где вам надо, вы задаете нужный формат, сейчас же вы просто перегоняете число в строку. В привязках за это если что отвечает `StringFormat`.

Comment: То есть вот вам простой [вывод](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRIZt.png), в `TextBlock` у меня всегда будет 5 символов, пустые заменяются нулями, лишнее само обрезается и конвертируется. Привязанное свойство у меня имеет тип `double`, конвертации какой либо в VM у меня нету, там просто `public double Value { get; set; } = 55.1;`, ну а в XAML я просто привязал нужный контрол к свойству, задав форматирование: `{Binding Value, StringFormat=00000}`. По этому я немного не понимаю, какую задачу вы решаете, зачем это кастомное преобразование, да и зачем `Value = number.ToString();`...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, работа с числом, как со строкой дает больше контроля над валидацией, в моем случае - над выводом сообщения об ошибке. Если работать с double, то в качестве ошибки выводится стандартное сообщение, а мне, например, нужно его изменить. Для этого и Value = number.ToString(). Все, чего я добиваюсь - это работа со строкой, как с числом, т.е. при вводе пользователем автоматически убираются лишние нули в начале, точка заменяется запятой, а при вводе нечисловых значений - выдаем ошибку в тултипе

Comment: А когда вам нужно будет число, которое написал пользователь например в другом VM, или вообще передать в М слой, что тогда? `double.Parse(Value)`? Вы ведь понимаете, что это костыль. Не, дело ваше конечно, но так явно не делается. И да, о каком "большем контроле" идет речь? Я у вас вижу только одну ошибку "не является числом", а это по умолчанию делает привязка сама, за вас.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь перемешать в кучу валидацию и конвертацию. Давайте немного проясним.

- Привязываться надо к свойствам нужного типа. Никаких промежуточных костылей не должно быть.
- `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` и правда мешает ввести точку, если привязка идет к числовому полю, например к `double`. Это лечится изменением поведения WPF.
- Далее, валидация должна быть отдельно, конвертация отдельно. Если они подчиняются общей логике, можно завести например статический класс, который будет содержать нужный обоим метод.
- `IDataErrorInfo` подходит только для уже распознанных данных, то есть когда `double` уже валидный, но вы хотите например наложить ограничение, чтобы он был к примеру положительным числом.

***Дисклеймер:** применять толерантность точка-запятая с числах с плавающей точкой - плохая идея. Какой дробный разделитель использовать - ответственность операционной системы, а не вашего кода. Так что из ниже предложенного решения я бы выкинул конвертер и `.Replace.Replace` из правила валидации. То что я использовал такие приемы вопреки здравому смылу - это просто чтобы показать вам, как возможно сделать то, что у вас происано в условиях вопроса.*

#### Настройка

Переопределение поведения WPF, чтобы оно пропускало ввод точки при привязке к `double` с применением `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkCompatibilityPreferences.KeepTextBoxDisplaySynchronizedWithTextProperty = false;
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
```

#### Конвертация

Хотите точки на запятые менять и пробелы удалять - пожалуйста

```cs
public class DoubleConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value is double number ? number.ToString("G") : string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is string input))
            throw new ArgumentException($"DoubleConverter.ConvertBack получил неверный тип {value.GetType().Name}, но ожидал {typeof(string).Name}");

        if (double.TryParse(input.Replace(".", ",").Replace(" ", ""), out double number))
            return number;
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

И подключить конвертер

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DoubleConverter x:Key="DoubleConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

#### Валидация

Стандартное сообщение `Value cannot 'sdfsd' be converted` не прикольное, хочется своё, это можно переопределить создав своё правило валидации.

```cs
public class DoubleValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        if (value is string input && double.TryParse(input.Replace(".", ",").Replace(" ", ""), out _))
            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        else
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Введите число");
    }
}
```

#### Разметка

```xml
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" FontSize="30" Width="100"
        TextAlignment="Center"
        ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Parameter.Value" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" ValidatesOnDataErrors="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:DoubleValidationRule/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

#### View Model

В результате того, что все поставленные вами условия в вопросе я выполнил выше, интерфейс `IDataErrorInfo` я просто выбрасываю

```cs
public class Parameter : ViewModelBase
{
    private double _value;

    public double Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            _value = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Value));
        }
    }

    public Parameter(double number)
    {
        Value = number;
    }
}
```

Comment: А смысл тут в конверторе? И `.Replace(".", ",").Replace(" ", "")`, серьезно? Это обязанности культуры, а пробелы и так не допустит привязка.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я всего-лишь показал автору, где нужно втыкать то что ему нужно. Сам бы я такими фокусами конечно заниматься не стал. А если бы и стал вводить толерантность к точка-запятая, то в обратную сторону с использованием при парсинге числа и при переводе в строку `InvariantCulture`. Моя задача была скорее показать доступные инструменты, нежели православным образом настроить поведение. Но вы совершенно правы.

Comment: Да, просто 1. Конвертор в примере не используется где либо, он как бы есть, да, но он не используется. 2. Полная его замена, это `{Binding Value, StringFormat=G}`, может стоит показать "как надо"? Касательно запятых, как я сказал выше, это культура, стоит тоже упомянуть про то, "как правильно", а то у нас на вопросы "как распарсить сброку с точкой", если дать вариант с `Replace`, сразу "по рукам надо бить", почему тогда тут не надо?) Я всеж считаю, что если даете ответ, то вы в некой мере учитель и стоит ученикам давать хотя бы правильное направление.

Comment: Благодарю. Анализируя все вышесказанное, понял, что моя задумка действительно костыльная. Но, все-таки, мне кажется, было бы удобнее, если бы пользователю не приходилось париться насчет разделителя, т.е. на входе разделитель менялся бы сам, в зависимости от текущей культуры. Подскажите, пожалуйста, насколько правильно использовать для этого вот такой конвертер - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufKjq.png ? Или, быть может, есть другие способы?

Comment: @Vladislav формат чисел - это не только десятичный разделитель, есть 3 варианта `1 000 000,00`, `1,000,000.00`, `1.000.000,00`. То есть при определенных условиях, например в финансовых форматах чисел вы начнете путать точку - десятиченый разделитель и точку - разделитель разрядов. Я бы советовал смириться с этим и принимать только тот формат чисел, который соответствует региональным настройкам операционной системы. Вам кажется, что вы решаете головную боль, а на самом деле вы ее создаете. В русской локализации разделитель десятичной дроби - запятая, и других разделителей быть не может.

Comment: @Vladislav отвечая прямо на _насколько правильно использовать для этого вот такой конвертер_ - правильнее всего его вообще не использовать. С другой стороны вы разработчик - вам и решать, как оно будет работать. Я всего-лишь делюсь опытом.