# C# WPF: Ввод в TextBox только строки формата Double с макс. 6 знаков после запятой

Tags: c#, wpf

В разметке имеется `TextBox`, в который нужно разрешить ввод только цифр и запятой. Но при этом запятую можно вводить только один раз и количество символов после нее не должно превышать **6**.

Изначально я пробовал посимвольно проверять состав строки и пытался добавлять исключения, но там очень много сложностей. Как сделать такое через привязки данных я тоже не понимаю - не удается установить параметр в `xaml`-разметке как [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361689/how-to-format-number-of-decimal-places-in-wpf-using-style-template):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={}{0:#,#.00}}" />
```

Он просто отказывается воспринимать параметр `StringFormat`.

Пока что, единственное компактное и максимально неграмотное решение, которое пришло мне на ум - пробовать конвертировать содержимое строки в `double` при каждом обновлении `TextBox.Text`. Это тратит много ресурсов и все равно работает некорректно:

```
private void AmountOnlyNumbers(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Convert.ToDouble(Amount.Text);
    }
    catch
    {
        if (Amount.Text.Length > 0) Amount.Text = Amount.Text.Remove(Amount.Text.Length - 1);
    }
}
```

**Как будет более правильно это сделать?**

Comment: `#,#.00` это что за формат такой? Вы можете ограничить количество символов в боксе, зачем рисовать ограничения точности? Просто прибиндить к double свойству, и готово, плюс ограничение на длину.

Comment: А понял, это американский формат, в вашем случае будет просто `0,######`. Похожий вопрос здесь раньше был https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282658/373567